# Translate Pythonic program logic into JavaScript to execute in the browser for React app

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

This is the basic structure of the landing page from my new React app, created according to the [standard documentation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My idea is to embed the logic of a Python script that I wrote- kind of simplistic "*proof of concept*"- into this React app, such that it can execute in the browser of the person viewing the page.

I've never built a React app before though- how can I include that python routine as part of the React app- presumably rewritten in JavaScript- so that it can execute inside of the browser?

Here is the crux of the Python function:

```
# This method determines whether or not the number is a Palindrome
def isPalindrome(x):
    x = '{:.2f}'.format(x).replace('.','')
    a, z = 0, len(x) - 1
    while a < z:
        if x[a] != x[z]:
            return False
        a += 1
        z -= 1
    return True
```

I've seen before that JavaScript can just have functions that are defined- for instance- at the bottom of the index page- and that they're just called by some procedural code to execute- pass them some variables- and so on- is that the right way? Maybe I should encapsulate it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is basically pure Javascript. So you would use something like:

```
   function isPalindrome(x){
        let y = x.Fixed(2).replace('.', '')
        z = y.length - 1
        for(let a=0; a++; a<y){
            if(y[a]!=y[z]){
                return false
            }
            a++
            z--
        }
        return true
    }
```

If you want to learn more about React, you should start by reading a bit about [Component Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).
EDIT: forgot to instantiate the a let

Answer (score -1):

http://www.skulpt.org/

You're looking for an "in-browser Python interpreter".

Here's one React implementation for you to guide yourself on. It doesn't have the small, snippet-sized scale I believe you seek, but the code will be useful nonetheless.

https://github.com/fatiherikli/fil